# Maintaining request scope in Express/Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, zone

I am using Express to expose a REST API in my Node.js application. When a REST request comes in, I extract the user information from the HTTP headers. I would like this information to be available throughout the life of this request, no matter what function I am in. An obvious but kludgy way is to pass around the user information as parameters to all function calls. Is there a better way? So far I have found the following solutions, but I am not sure if they are ready for prime time:

1. [StrongLoop Zone Library](https://github.com/strongloop/zone): Docs say "The zone library and documentation are still under development: there are bugs, missing features, and limited documentation."
2. [Continuation-Local Storage](https://github.com/othiym23/node-continuation-local-storage): Not sure if this is slated to be part of Node.js. This [issue](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5243) at the end recommends looking at StrongLoop zone.
3. [Node.js Domains](https://nodejs.org/api/domain.html): Does not look like this actually took off.

Comment: So you're looking for "requestable context"? So that whenever you need context that wasn't passed in directly, you can request it somehow?

Comment: You can attach variables to `req` directly.Try adding the line `req.myObject = { color: "red" }`

Comment: Well, in that case I will need to pass `req` around to all layers of the app, which is exactly what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Any solutions yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're still looking, but a while back I built [`express-http-context`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-context) for this very purpose.  It's an express middleware that sits on top of `cls-hooks` (formerly `continuation-local-storage`).

Full disclosure: this is an npm package that I built and maintain.

Comment: Thanks, Steve. I am no longer looking for this solution, but I will keep express-http-context in mind.